# when focus EditText ,EditText didnot pop out the SoftKeyboard

Tags: android

Yes.It is my question.When I using edittext in my layout.when I focus or touch the Edittext,them didnot pop out the soft keyboard.

this is my layout:

```

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1.0" >

        <RelativeLayout
          ...........................
          ...........................
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1.0" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/detail_query_txt"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:inputType="phone" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/detail_query_but"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detail_query_txt"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:text="@string/word_query" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

```
Now:I didnot write any code in my java class file

I try all the way the Network tell us,all it failed.
this is the way i test:
`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"`  add to Activity in Mainifest  ----> failed
it pop out the Soft keyboard,but pointer to class,not the edittext

and so on...
someone help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` from your LinearLayout.
I tried your code, it worked.

Hope it helps.

**EDIT :**

```
Explaination:
```

the attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` simply **blocks** your `LinearLayout` **to give focus** to the decendant view .

Decendants of `LinearLayout`= all the child views of `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
    <activity
         android:name="Activity"
         android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the point where you want to display the keyboard (may be in oCreate?)

```
EditText mEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName-);

    ((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
        .showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```