# My items in my listview are not reacting to OnItemClick

Tags: android

This is my Layout file for a row with all them parameters need to prevent the elements from being clickable (at least i thought they are all).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/measuredata_list_row_textview_date"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/measuredata_list_row_textview_time"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/measuredata_list_row_textview_value"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/measuredata_list_row_imageview_mood"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageview_photo_description" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

and the code from the activity:

```
public class MeasureDataListFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener, MeasureDataGetSelectionCallback, MeasureDataGetCallback {
    private SessionManagerPreferences sessionManagerPreferences = null;
    private SessionManagerSingleton sessionManagerSingleton = null;
    private SessionManagerMeasureDataList sessionManagerMeasureDataList = null;
    private MeasureDataListAdapter adapter = null;
    private ListView listRowParent = null;
    private Button buttonChoose = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.sessionManagerPreferences = new SessionManagerPreferences(this.getActivity());
        this.sessionManagerSingleton = SessionManagerSingleton.getInstance(this.getActivity());
        this.sessionManagerMeasureDataList = SessionManagerMeasureDataList.getInstance();

        if(this.sessionManagerMeasureDataList.getMeasureDataList() == null) {
            this.sessionManagerMeasureDataList.setMeasureDataList(new MeasureDataList());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_measuredata_list_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        this.listRowParent = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.measuredata_list_row_parent);
        this.buttonChoose = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.measuredata_list_fragment_button_choose);
        this.buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);

        this.adapter = new MeasureDataListAdapter(this.getActivity(), this.sessionManagerMeasureDataList.getMeasureDataList().getMeasureDataListEntries());
        this.listRowParent.setAdapter(this.adapter);
        this.listRowParent.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case  R.id.measuredata_list_fragment_button_choose : {
                this.performChooseDates();
            } break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.v("MeasureDataListFragment", "Position: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasureDataGetSelectionCompleted(final String fromYear, final String fromMonth, final String fromDay, final String toYear, final String toMonth, final String toDay) {
        String email = null;
        String password = null;
        String from = fromDay + "." + fromMonth + "." + fromYear;
        String to = toDay + "." + toMonth + "." + toYear;

        if(this.sessionManagerSingleton.isLoggedIn()) {
            email = this.sessionManagerSingleton.getEmail();
            password = this.sessionManagerSingleton.getPassword();
        } else {
            Map<String, String> userData = this.sessionManagerPreferences.getUserDetails();

            email = userData.get(Globals.KEY_EMAIL);
            password = userData.get(Globals.KEY_PASSWORD);
        }

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        MeasureDataGetTask measureDataGetTask = new MeasureDataGetTask(email, password, from, to);
        MeasureDataGetDialogFragment measureDataGetDialogFragment = new MeasureDataGetDialogFragment(measureDataGetTask, this);

        measureDataGetDialogFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasureDataGetCompleted(StatusMeasureDataGet status, MeasureDataGetPOJO measureDataGetPOJO) {
        switch(status) {
            case MEASUREDATA_TRANSFER_SUCCESSFUL: {
                this.sessionManagerMeasureDataList.setMeasureDataList(measureDataGetPOJO);
                this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } break;
            case ERROR_CONNECTION_FAILED: {
                String title = this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error);
                String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_connection_failed);

                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(title, message, this.getFragmentManager());
            } break;
            case ERROR_IO_EXCEPTION: {
                String title = this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error);
                String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_io_exception);

                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(title, message, this.getFragmentManager());
            } break;
            case ERROR_JSON_EXCEPTION: {
                String title = this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error);
                String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_json_exception);

                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(title, message, this.getFragmentManager());
            } break;
            case ERROR_NO_DATA_FOUND: {
                String title = this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error);
                String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_not_data_found);

                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(title, message, this.getFragmentManager());
            } break;
            case ERROR_PROTOCOL_EXCEPTION: {
                String title = this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error);
                String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_protocol_exception);

                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(title, message, this.getFragmentManager());
            } break;
            case ERROR_WRONG_PARAMETERS: {
                String title = this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_error);
                String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_wrong_parameters);

                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(title, message, this.getFragmentManager());
            } break;
            case ERROR_WRONG_USER_OR_PW: {
                String title = this.getResources().getString(R.string.title_input_error);
                String message = this.getResources().getString(R.string.message_wrong_mail_or_pw);

                DialogManager.showAlertDialog(title, message, this.getFragmentManager());
            } break;
        }
    }

    private void performChooseDates() {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        MeasureDataSelectionDialogFragment measureDataGetSelectionDialogFragment = new MeasureDataSelectionDialogFragment(this);

        measureDataGetSelectionDialogFragment.show(fragmentTransaction, null);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately none of my rows is reacting to the click from OnItemClickListener.
What else do i have to declear to get this working? There is no output at all to the log file when i click any row. its like i never added an OnItemClickListener to the ListView.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602924/android-listview-item-click-is-not-working/23603110#23603110

Comment: it wokrs but in my opinion it is not a good looking workaround. i would rather understand why the ontimeclicklistener isnt reacting.

Comment: Can you post whole activity?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20486114/when-focus-edittext-edittext-didnot-pop-out-the-softkeyboard, add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on your inflated linearlayout

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything.